# Directory is not created in Xamarin app (Android)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I need to create a directory to store user video files in Internal Storage.

In some part of the code I have this:

```
        var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyVideos);
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
```

When I debug, path variable is actually: "/data/data/com.companyname.MyApp/files/Videos"

When I browse device files, the closest target folder is this: "This PC\MyDevice\Internal storage\Android\data"

When I browse that folder, no new folder was created. I was expecting to have com.companyname.MyApp/files/Videos folder structure, but it was not created, even when no exception was thrown.

How can I do it?

Thanks

Jaime

Comment: Did you add use permission in **AndroidManifest.xml** ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [File provider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider) in the manifest

Define file_paths.xml

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="my_images" path="images/"/>
    <files-path name="my_docs" path="docs/"/>
</paths>
```

and add it into manifest

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.mydomain.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
```

Comment: That is for Xamarin? I added file_paths.xml inside Resources\values folder but when compiling, an error telling that "Invalid start tag paths" is shown.

Comment: Create xml folder and then add the file

Comment: even when now project compiled it does not work. I have created manually Videos folder in /Android/data/com.company.MyApp/files/Videos even when calling Environment method path "/data/data/com.company.MyApp/files/Videos" is returned. Well, then I used System.IO.File.Exists(videoPath) to test if file exists, but it does not. I have replaced the first "/data" by "/Android", but the file is not found either.  I think I am pointing the wrong folder. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I had a misconception about Internal and External storage.

What I was seeing in Windows Explorer is in fact, external storage, so I used:

```
Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryMovies)
```

That points to the "Movies" directory where I could save the MP4 file in order to view in the Android device.

Regards
Jaime